# RSS reader unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing

Build a android simple RSS reader application ,I have simple class "ReaderAppActivity" which use onCreate method as following to parsing a particular RSS site

```
public class ReaderAppActivity extends Activity {
/** 
 * This method creates main application view
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        // Create RSS reader
        RssReader rssReader = new RssReader("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss");
        // Get a ListView from main view
        ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView);

        // Create a list adapter
        ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rssReader.getItems());
        // Set list adapter for the ListView
        itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set list view item click listener
        itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(rssReader.getItems(), this));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Reader", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Now want to develop a Junit testing really don't understand on

1) which  parameter I should taste my app ? for example assertest, timeout

2) For internet base project is there any unit  testing tutorial for beginners ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html

In the manuals you find answers for your questions. Also it will help to you to understand what you need to test (1st question).